# How can I add text on an Image using html5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to add text on an image using HTML5. How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the image into a canvas (using `drawImage()`), then draw text on the canvas (using `fillText()`).

If you want to you can then take the image data from the canvas using `toDataUrl()` and post that data to the server for image persistence.

If you only need it for client side visibility you have a much simpler solution that doesn't use html5. just overlay a text over the image using absolute positioning.

Comment: Vague question, great answer.